# Sort array by date via re-rendering

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react but I'm facing a small issue. I'm building up a social platform for practice where user's are able to post, like and comment. I'm using Change stream and socket.io to detect any changes in my database.

Everything works perfectly fine but what I'd like to know is, that when I create a post I'd like the state that has been set to be sorted via date before mapping through the posts. knowing that when the useEffect is triggered the data retrieved would be sorted by date instead of scrolling all the way down to the new post created.

Here is my code snippet. I've tried different ways to sorting but unfortunately I'm unable to achieve it. I'd like the posts to be sorted by date when re-rendered to be displayed if that make sense.

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const handler = (item) => {
         setPosts((oldPosts) => [...oldPosts.filter(p => p._id !== item._id), item]);
    };
    socket.on('posts', handler);
    return () => socket.off('posts', handler);
}, []);
```

Comment: When a new post created and you retrieved it from socket you should add it to first element of `posts` array because it's the newest one. I think there is no need to sort. Maybe I don't understand what you want exactly.

Comment: @NimaEbrazeh What I actually want is that every time I create, like or comment on a post or any changes occur on the post, I always want to make sure that the order of the posts displayed in the UI are sorted by the date posted (posts.postedOn). What you mentioned slightly worked, but once I liked the post or any changes occur it seems to lose order, so I'd always like to ensure that the posts are sorted no matter the changes made, thus not effecting the UI, is that abit more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well actually we have two possibility:

1- updated `item` is new. So put it at first index of array.

2- updated `item` is duplicate. Then just update it's value using map.

```
const handler = (item) => {
    setPosts((oldPosts) => {
        const findItem = oldPosts.find((post) => post._id === item._id);
        if (findItem) {
          return oldPosts.map((post) => (post._id === item._id ? item : post));
        } else {
          return [item, ...oldPosts];
        }
    });
};
```

Be aware that in this method you should sort posts on the first render of the component by Date.

Comment: I understand what you mean regarding to the methods mentioned, but when I like, unlike, comment the changes still occur in the posts, thus moving whatever action occured on a post to be placed first, so I've made a unlisted video on youtube with a visual representation on what I mean, when the posts loses order once a change occurs, which does make sense why it would happen, but on the other hand I would like to keep the posts in order when a like, unlike or comment action occurs, only when a post is created should it be moved to the first index like shown above. https://youtu.be/lBHEO3Yrt5A

Comment: I watch the video. I think my code is working in like, unlike, comment changes because the `item` is find in the list and then `else` block runs. And in else method it just replaces the item and the order of posts does not change.

Comment: It's odd since in the video, was the snippet I used that was provided by you, so I don't understand why it's not working

Comment: Do you have another `useEffect` which update `posts` array?

Comment: not at all, only one that would call an Get request to the API endpoint to retrieve all posts but only once the page has been refreshed, thus not focused on the changes being occured.  ```useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("/api/post/posts",config).then((response) => {
            setPosts(response.data);
        });
      // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);```

Comment: I just update the code in my answer. Please try it. Also check that the condition `post._id === item._id` is met or not.

Comment: Thank youuuu!! works perfectly! I really do appreciate your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is run this code before setPosts and pass date sorted array to setPosts by using the following code.

```
yourArray.sort(function (a, b) {
  // Turn your strings into dates, and then subtract them
  // to get a value that is either negative, positive, or zero.
  return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
});
```